Blender Geometry Nodes Dissolve Effect - Random Delete Some Instances?
i'm attempting to make a dissolve effect that is driven by proximity to an Empty.
So far, i've created a mesh to volume, then populated that with points/instances of a brick.  I have the Empty shrinking the brick instances when in close proximity to the Empty.
The problem is that it looks too organized, perfect, and unnatural.
So, how do I randomly delete some of the instances affected by the Empty?
This is my first attempt, with a bit of translation for variety's sake:

Here is my node setup:

Thanks!  There are other effects im trying for related to this topic that might impact this one, but Stack Exchange wouldn't let me include them all in one post despite the problems being interconnected. Please see my post history if you're curious and want to help out.
Thank you!

Just use a noise texture into a Greater Than/Less Than node with a threshold.

